# Unable to open a file using a custom program that has been added to 'open with' list

Tags: .desktop, mono

This is essentially a windows program for editing subtitles. I've been using another program called `mono` to run it. The program itself runs fine.

I then created a `.desktop` file that looks like this.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=SubtitleEdit
Comment=Opens subtitle files
Exec=mono /home/aurora/Downloads/SE364/SubtitleEdit.exe%U
Path=/home/aurora/Downloads/SE364/
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/transmission.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

I allowed it to launch as a program in properties.
I copied this file to `~/.local/share/applications` so that I can launch the .desktop file with the program.

*Curiously, only the file in Desktop then gave me an option 'Allow launching' when I right-click it. And it launches the program.  The copy of this file in another folder didn't give me that option and it doesn't launch from there either. I'm just including this fact so that it may be relevant to solving this problem.*

I had to add `%U` to the `Exec` line so that I can add it to the list of '`open with`' applications.
Without that, when I type that line in the terminal, the program runs.

I then tried to open an .srt file using this program and nothing happens.
Now, what I have done wrong or haven't yet done that this is the case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a space before the placeholder `%U`.

If you do not, the system sees:

`mono /home/aurora/Downloads/SE364/SubtitleEdit.exe'/path/to/the/file'`

hence does not find a file `file` in a not existing path `/home/aurora/Downloads/SE364/SubtitleEdit.exe'/path/to/the/`.

With the space, the following valid command will be passed to the system:

`mono /home/aurora/Downloads/SE364/SubtitleEdit.exe '/path/to/the/file'`